# Compile objective c in xcode 7 without the simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

I want to learn pure Objective C (not iOS developing yet) so I download Xcode 7 ide.

I want to write a simple algorithm and see my results on a console without firing the on screen simulator!

Can I do it?

Comment: Write a command line program? It's one of the options when you make a new project...

Comment: @Arc676 Can you plz be more specific? Where is that option?

Comment: When you create a project don't choose an iOS project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write an algorithm that doesn't have a GUI, create a command line tool.

When creating your project, go to OS X > Application > Command Line Tool.

You can choose to write your application in C or C++. You will be left with a `main.c` or `main.cpp` file based on your choice.

Rename the file to end in `.mm` to let it have both C(++) *and* Objective-C code. To use the Objective-C libraries, you will need a header file (`.h`) and you will need to import the desired library with ObjC syntax.

Example: `main.h`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

When you run the program, you will be able to use the console to interact with your program.

[image: new project dialog]

Comment: Thanks for your time man.. So simple.. I am pretty new to ios

Answer (score 1):

*For Swift:* I would use a `Playground` using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>.

Or in Xcode `File > New > Playground`

Comment: Playground with Objective-C?

Comment: @Eiko, you are correct, that would be for Swift not obj-c